# How to pass multiple arguments to spawned threads (Mbed)?

Tags: c++, stm32, mbed

I use Mbed RTOS and I need to pass multiple arguments to the threaded function.

There is an example in API docs:

```
#include "mbed.h"

Thread thread;
DigitalOut led1(LED1);
volatile bool running = true;

// Blink function toggles the led in a long running loop
void blink(DigitalOut *led) {
    while (running) {
        *led = !*led;
        wait(1);
    }
}

// Spawns a thread to run blink for 5 seconds
int main() {
    thread.start(callback(blink, &led1));
    wait(5);
    running = false;
    thread.join();
}
```

But there is only one argument to pass.

Is there a convenient way to pass multiple arguments? I don't like the idea to put them into a struct and pass the struct. But I can't see any other way to do it.

Comment: You could use a `std::tuple` instead of defining a new `struct`. But there is unlikely to be any other way, as such callback systems typically only offer a single 'user data' pointer.

Comment: Thank you! `std::tuple` is surely better than `struct` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `std::tuple<>` instead of defining a new `struct`. This is simpler in most cases, although as the number of argument members goes up, you might find yourself wanting a struct after all, to get names for them instead of having to `std::get()` by type or index.

There is unlikely to be any other way, as such callback systems typically only offer a single 'user data' pointer, and my brief googling about Mbed suggest it is the same.

Comment: most of the std::.... are not usable in the uC world (including tuples). They are far too expensive.

Comment: @P__J__ Won't optimisation get rid of all the cruft used to implement `std::tuple` internally?

Comment: @P__J__ Nah, I think you retain the burden of proof on that one.

Comment: You cant proof it. C++ libraries were written with large computers (ie with a lots of memory and computing power). In the uC world you have a very limited resources RAM far below 1MB and limited computing power.  Use of the dynamic allocation has to be avoided at any price as well. Tupples relay on it. Imagine that you have 2kb of heap. How quickly it will become fragmented?

Comment: @P__J__ In what world, and why, do tuples 'rely on dynamic allocation'?!? They are value classes that hold each element directly (usually via recursive inheritance AFAIK)